# Why are the orbit of planets usually ellipses?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion, planets, celestial-mechanics

There has been a similar question about planets' orbits being ellipses but the answer circulates around how the circle is a special type of orbit which doesn't really answer my question.

Elaborate Question: What are the factors or any mathematical idea or any law that suggests the elliptical orbits of a binary system? How does it explain the elliptical orbit concept? Or is it based simply on observations?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/112668/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/56657/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Hi, @Qmechanic, If this is a duplicate could you state why and how this relates to this because i know it involves Kepler's law but how is the question

Comment: Elliptical orbits were stated in Kepler's first law as the result of observations. Newton showed that Kepler's laws can be derived from his theory of gravity.

Comment: https://astronomy.swin.edu.au/cosmos/c/Conic+sections  "The four classic conic sections can be produced by the intersection of a plane through a cone. The four conic sections are the circle, ellipse, parabola and hyperbola." "Curiously, in astronomy, the Newtonian solutions to the two-body problem forces binary stars, planets and comets to trace a path that always corresponds to one of the four conic sections."  For the existing planets, the probability they would be trapped in the symmetric in axis  orbit of a circle is much smaller than the asymmetric of an elipse (answering title)

Comment: What do you mean. _usually_?

Comment: @nielsnielsen Circular orbits [_are_](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1250897) elliptical.